# map through an object skipping some elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, slice

Wondering how could I display a separator at any position in JSX? For instance, I have the following list which displays text when clicking on the item:

[image]

The code is the following:

```
<Accordion>
  {items.map((item, index) => (
    <AccordionItem key={item.id} item={item} index={index} />
  ))}
</Accordion>
```

Having an object like this declaring the content of the list:

```
const items = [
    { label: "One", content: "lorem ipsum for more, see https://one.com" },
    { label: "Two", content: "lorem ipsum for more, see https://two.com" },
    {
      label: "Three",
      content: "lorem ipsum for more, see https://three.com",
    },
  ];
```

Now, I'd like to add a separator after the label "Two" to get something like this:
[image]

If we try the following way, I get active the element in index 0 and element in index2:

```
<Accordion>
  {items.slice(0, 2).map((item, index) => (
    <AccordionItem key={item.id} item={item} index={index} />
  ))}
  <hr />
  {items.slice(2).map((item, index) => (
    <AccordionItem key={item.id} item={item} index={index} />
  ))}
</Accordion>
```

Then, getting this incorrect result:
[image]

Why it is happening this? Because my Accordion object is the following:

```
import { useState, createContext } from "react";

export const AccordionContext = createContext({
  activeItemIndex: 0,
  setActiveItemIndex: () => 0,
});

export const Accordion = (props) => {
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <AccordionContext.Provider value={{ activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex }}>
      <ul>{props.children}</ul>
    </AccordionContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

At the beginning *activeItemIndex* is 0, so when applying slice(2) the first element is also index 0 (however the element is at index 2).

How could I get the line right after the second element in the list?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can conditionally render the separator based on the current index.

```js
...
return (
    <Accordion>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <AccordionItem item={item} index={index} />
          {index === 1 && <hr />}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </Accordion>
  );
```

*[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-qwohbh?file=src%2FApp.js)*

---

##### Dynamic Solution for any index value:

So if you see the above solution works for specific index i.e. `1`(means the second `<AccordionItem />`). To make the separator position dynamic, you can pass a prop to the `Accordion` component specifying the separator indices which you can then leverage to conditionally render the separator.

```js
export const Accordion = ({ separators, children }) => {
  const [activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
    <AccordionContext.Provider value={{ activeItemIndex, setActiveItemIndex }}>
      <ul>{children(separators)}</ul>
    </AccordionContext.Provider>
  );
};
// To use
 // const separatorIndices = [2]; // or any dynamic index which you want to provide.
  const separatorIndex = 1; // or this whichever suits your needs

  return (
    <Accordion>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
          <AccordionItem item={item} index={index} />
          {/* {separatorIndices.includes(index) && <hr />} */}
          {index === separatorIndex && <hr />}
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </Accordion>
  );
```

*[Demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ylhfmk?file=src%2FApp.js)*

Comment: Agree, I thought it would be another way not using conditional rendering, but it seems it is the way to go.

Comment: @JarochoEngineer conditional rendering approach will not have issues since it is one of the norms actually and probably the only way

Answer (score 1):

You can use the index of the array to display the separator conditionally.

```
 <Accordion>
   {items.map((item, index) => (
      <React.Fragment key={item.id}>
        <AccordionItem item={item} index={index} />
        {index === 1 && <hr />}
      </React.Fragment>
    ))}
  </Accordion>
```